# Limit text input on IText or Textbox

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to create a text input on top of a fabric canvas using either IText or Textbox objects. This seems to be accomplished pretty well on http://impretty.me, which is using Fabric, but I can't seem to replicate what they're doing here. I'd either like to be able to set a max width/max character count on IText or limit the Textbox object to a single line.

My issue is that setting a width on IText is ineffective, and even though the width parameter works on Textbox, I need to keep the text to a single line. Scaling text, as is seen on http://impretty.me would be nice but isn't necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for the text box and the interaction I've worked out at this point is below.

```
const text = new fabric.IText('Type Your Message', {
  originY: 'center',
  hoverCursor: 'text',
  left: 210,
  top: 825,
  width: 300,
  fontFamily: 'Permanent Marker',
  fontSize: 50,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  id: 'text'
})
canvas.add(text)

text.on('changed', function (options) {
  if (this.width >= 635) {
    const newText = this.text.slice(0, -1)
    this.text = newText
    this.hiddenTextarea.value = newText
    console.log(this)
  }
})
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried??

Comment: Hi @Durga I've updated my post. Basically what I've worked out checks the width of the text object and, if it's beyond a certain limit, prevents additional characters being added. It feels pretty hack-y, and it also may be interfering with the fontFamily declaration (font becomes unstyled unpredictably), though whether that's truly a related issue or not I haven't been able to determine. If there's a better way, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can resize down the text to fit inside the bounding box

```
sizeDownTextNew = function(canvasObj, limit_height, limit_width )
{

    if(typeof (canvasObj) == "undefined" || canvasObj == null)
        return;
    var counter = 250; //Maximum of 250iterations to size down
    var initial_height = limit_height;
    var max = canvasObj.get('fontSize');
    var min = 6; //This is our minimum size
    var foundmin=0; //Flag if minimum is met
    var ratio = max;
    //Now reduce the size of actual text font size property
    while(canvasObj.height+2<canvasObj._getTextHeight()) //While the height of text is larger then actual text, try reducing the lineHeight
    {

        var fontSize = parseFloat(canvasObj.get('fontSize'));

        fontSize=fontSize - fontSize/max; //reduce the size with a set ratio

        if(fontSize > min) //If main font is greater then min font, we will now reduce
        {

            canvasObj.set('fontSize', fontSize);
            canvasObj.height = initial_height

        canvasObj.canvas.renderAll();
        canvasObj.height = initial_height;
        canvasObj.setCoords();
        canvasObj.canvas.renderAll();

        if(counter == 0) //Failsafe to exit the while loop if no condition is met
            break;
    }


    counter = 300;
    while(limit_width<canvasObj._getTextWidth()) //While the width of text is larger then actual text, try reducing it
    {
        var fontSize = parseFloat(canvasObj.get('fontSize'));

        fontSize=fontSize - fontSize/ratio; //reduce the size with a set ratio

            canvasObj.setCoords();
            canvasObj.canvas.renderAll();

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        canvasObj.width = limit_width;
        counter -- ;
        if(counter == 0)
        {

            break;
        }

    }


}
```

and then call this function like

```
text.on('changed', function (options) {
```

sizeDownTextNew(this,500,60);
})

Answer (score 0):

To limit text for fabric js Version 2+,
We need to override the onInput function as follows

```js
onInput: function(e) {

  if(this.width > this.maxWidth) {
    return;
  }

  if(this._textLines.length > this.maxLines) {
    return;
  }

  // Call parent class method
  this.callSuper('onInput', e);
}
```

Note: maxWidth - to limit width
and maxLines - to limit height / lines in text box.
Edit: Fixed Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 'maxLength' to textarea.

```
    this.on("editing:entered", () => {
      if (this.hiddenTextarea) {
        // limit textarea length
        this.hiddenTextarea.maxLength = 40;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to create a new Fabric class that extends the Fabric.Textbox class. Here's an example:

```js
const LimitedTextbox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
  onInput: function (e: any) {
    const oldText = this.text;

    /**
     * Sometimes, when you insert a line break, it doesn't appear to Fabric as an 'insertLineBreak' but simply sets the date to null.
     * Therefore, it's important to check that it's not deleting any characters, and if the date is null, it means that a new line is being inserted
     */
    if (e.inputType === 'insertLineBreak' || (e.inputType !== 'deleteContentBackward' && !e.data)) {
      this._textBeforeEdit = oldText;
      this.hiddenTextarea.value = oldText;
      this.text = oldText;
      return;
    } else if (e.inputType !== 'deleteContentBackward') {
      if (this.width > this.maxWidth) {
        this._textBeforeEdit = oldText;
        this.hiddenTextarea.value = oldText;
        this.text = oldText;

        // If you want to enable scaling to keep writing, there are issues when you delete a portion of text and not just a single character
        //
        // this.fontSizeList = [...(this.fontSizeList || []), this.fontSize];
        // this.fontSize *= this.maxWidth / (this.width + 1);
        // this.width = this.maxWidth;
        return;
      }

      if (this._textLines.length > this.maxLines) {
        this._textBeforeEdit = oldText;
        this.hiddenTextarea.value = oldText;
        this.text = oldText;
        return;
      }
    } else {
      // If you want to enable scaling to keep writing, there are issues when you delete a portion of text and not just a single character
      //
      // const lastFontSize = this.fontSizeList?.pop();
      // if (lastFontSize) {
      //   this.fontSize = lastFontSize;
      // }

      /**
       * It's needed because otherwise, if I write many characters, he automatically adjusts the width even if the visible text doesn't change.
       * So, every time I delete something, I reset the width.
       * I do it during deletion; otherwise, if I do it in the maxWidth check, I never block it, and it would keep writing
       */
      this.width = this.maxWidth;
    }

    this.callSuper('onInput', e);
  },
});

...

textbox = new LimitedTextbox('custom text', {
  maxLines: 1,
  maxWidth: 100,
});
```